# Creating a calculated field in a workday report

Tags: reporting, calculated-columns, calculated-field, workday-api

I would like to understand how I could create a new field called "Field 1" in my workday report.

The logic for this field is – if there is a "Yes" in "field 2" OR a "Yes" in "field 3, then return a 0 in "Field 1".

If Both "field 2" and "field 3" are blank then return the number from another field in the report, called "field 4".

I am not sure if I have to create two seperate calculated fields and use them together to answer this question. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

I tried creating the calculated field myself using the functions "Evaluate Expression Band" and "True/False Condition" but was not able to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a value from another field, you need to use the evaluate Expression, not the Evaluate Expression Band. The band type only takes text/number inputs.

The Evaluate Expression will let you choose a field for your return value. You may need to convert Field 4 to a text value if it is a single instance field. You can do that by using Substring Text or Concatenate text calculated fields.